# Unknown column 'narozeni' in 'field list'

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, discord, discord.js

Hello Im making database record in my discord.js bot. But im steel getting this error:

```
/home/container/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:437
      throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
      ^
Error: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'narozeni' in 'field list'
    at Query.Sequence._packetToError (/home/container/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:47:14)
    at Query.ErrorPacket (/home/container/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:79:18)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (/home/container/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:291:23)
    at Parser._parsePacket (/home/container/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:433:10)
    at Parser.write (/home/container/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:43:10)
    at Protocol.write (/home/container/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:38:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/container/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:88:28)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/container/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:526:10)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:527:28)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:324:12)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (/home/container/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Connection.query (/home/container/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:198:25)
    at Handshake.<anonymous> (/home/container/commands/postava.js:132:20)
    at Handshake.<anonymous> (/home/container/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:526:10)
    at Handshake._callback (/home/container/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:488:16)
    at Handshake.Sequence.end (/home/container/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:83:24)
    at Handshake.Sequence.OkPacket (/home/container/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:92:8)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (/home/container/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:291:23)
    at Parser._parsePacket (/home/container/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:433:10)
    at Parser.write (/home/container/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:43:10) {
  code: 'ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR',
  errno: 1054,
  sqlMessage: "Unknown column 'narozeni' in 'field list'",
  sqlState: '42S22',
  index: 0,
  sql: 'INSERT INTO charaktery (jmeno, prijmeni, datumnarozeni, vek, cisloprukazu, discord, roblox) VALUES (`jmeno`, `prijmeni`, `narozeni`, `vek`, `randomp`, `discord.id`, `roblox`)'
}
```

**Code:**

```
             con.connect(function(err) {
               if (err) throw err;
               console.log("Connected!");
               var sql = "INSERT INTO charaktery (jmeno, prijmeni, datumnarozeni, vek, cisloprukazu, discord, roblox) VALUES (`jmeno`, `prijmeni`, `narozeni`, `vek`, `randomp`, `discord.id`, `roblox`)";
               con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
                 if (err) throw err;
                 console.log("1 record inserted");
               });
             });
```

**Db:**

[Image here!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9fFA.png)

I want to make record in database. I actually tried to give on values `. But still happens same error

Comment: A string delimiter is a single quote not a backtick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using single or double quotes in the raw sql query. For example:

```js
var sql = "INSERT INTO charaktery (jmeno, prijmeni, datumnarozeni, vek, cisloprukazu, discord, roblox) VALUES ('jmeno', 'prijmeni', 'narozeni', 'vek', 'randomp', 'discord.id', 'roblox')";
```

Backticks are not used in this way in SQL

Comment: Ty but i need to give to values from slash comannd so from const jmeno = <get from slash comannd>

Comment: @votavl you mean in discord slash command? Not sure maybe you can ask another question for that if that is the ask...

Comment: Um yea i writed it wrong. Yes i already constated string from slash comannd. I dont know how to give this const into sql insert.

Comment: @votavl search for how to write prepared statement in your library you are using... it will be something like (just an example of some library): `con.query('INSERT INTO posts SET title=?', title, <callback>)`
 https://www.w3resource.com/node.js/nodejs-mysql.php

Comment: nvm. I find out how to use it. This wont work you need to give there                ```var sql = "INSERT INTO charaktery (jmeno, prijmeni, datumnarozeni, vek, cisloprukazu, discord, roblox) VALUES ('" + jmeno + "', '" + prijmeni + "', '" + narozeni + "', '" + vek + "', '" + randomp + "', '" + clovek.id + "', '" + roblox + "')"```